# Parcel map and/or snow load KMZ?

Tags: usa, geospatial, kml

I'm looking for two KMZ files that I can import into Google Earth:

1. which will show me the parcel outlines
2. will give me local snow load information

I need this information for a few counties in Northern California only.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I think this should be researched/asked as two separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

Some work is going to have to be put in here, but this should be what you seek:

### Snow Load Information

[Ground Snow Load by Location](http://snowload.atcouncil.org/)

Alot (if not all) of California's Snow Load Information should be accessible on each county's website/portal/etc.
[Here is El Dorado County's Snow Load Information](http://www.edcgov.us/Building/Snow_Load_Information.aspx)
Or you can [contact California County Building Officials (list of contacts)](http://www.fs.fed.us/t-d/snow_load/links.htm#californiac)

#### Miscellaneous California Snow/Snow Load Resources

[Snow - California Data Exchange Center](http://cdec.water.ca.gov/snow/current/snow/index.html)
[National Snow Load Information](http://www.fs.fed.us/t-d/snow_load/states.htm)

### Parcels Data

These resources are not KML/KMZ, but there are a number of resources that can be utilized for conversion.
[California Parcels data (shapefiles)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138388/california-state-parcel-data)
[Open Addresses](https://openaddresses.io/) - Not Parcels data, but they do have a side project collecting Parcels data. If the data you seek is proving to be extremely hard to find, contacting the group could be very helpful.

### Tools for Converting to KML/KMZ

[GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) is the end all tool for this, however it is not the most friendliest if you are uncomfortable with code/command line.
[MapShaper](http://mapshaper.org/) is web based and easy for all users. You can upload shapefiles here and download them as GeoJSON.
[GeoJSON.io](http://geojson.io/) also web based, also super easy for all; you can the upload the GeoJSON files here, and convert/download them as KML/KMZ.